# Multiple containers with multiple outbound IPs

Tags: routing, ip, ipv6

Scenario: Server with multiple docker containers running inside, that can be configured to perform requests with different outbound ip addresses.

Is this even possible? I have some knowledge gaps regarding ip assignment methods, let's say if you buy 20 ip v6 addresses how can you assign them to each container?

Just want a correction or some guidance to see if this is a valid setup or just an incorrect approach.

Comment: You don't buy 20 IPv6 addresses, you get a `/64` subnetwork (18 quintillion addresses) or a `/48` subnetwork (1 sextillion addresses). Docker can automatically assign IPv6 addresses given a network prefix (cf. [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-ipv6))

Comment: Could you explain how this addresses are given? Or forward me to any documentation that could help me to understand this process better?

Comment: [This article](https://michael.stapelberg.ch/posts/2018-12-12-docker-ipv6/) might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 1):

As many globally routable addresses as you need is the point of IPv6. So forget about counting IP addresses, count nets instead.

In your organization's address plan, allocate a few /64 subnets for container networking. One site should get a /48 at least, these are plentiful.

Then use these for container networking, however you implement that. One /64 can fit the entire MAC address space and then some, but there are enough to use a /64 on every container host. So plenty of room to let Docker generate based on MAC, some static scheme, a fancy container orchestration system, or whatever you want.